# Setting field name as URL for proper getter and setter gives Checkstyle error

Tags: java, getter-setter

may be a stupid question, but just want to ask.
I have a Java class with some fields and it's getters and setters.

```
public class Parameters {

    private String URL;

    public String getURL() {
        return URL;
    }

    public void setURL(String uRL) {
        URL = uRL;
    }
}
```

Checkstyle will give error as

> Name 'URL' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'.

So I changed to `url` and generated getters and setters with Eclipse.

```
public class Parameters {

    private String url;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

I want the method name to be `getURL` and `setURL`. 
**Is it better I change the method names manually or is there any other way?**

**NB :** 
In case I have to search for methods based on field names using

```
java.beans.BeanInfo
java.beans.IntrospectionException
java.beans.Introspector
java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
```

for `url`, it will search for only `getUrl` and `setUrl`.

Comment: If you want to be pedantic, the Java code conventions specifies that acronyms should be in uppercase (except the first letter), so `uRL` would be the correct "spelling" for the attribute. Of course, automated tools do not know what is an acronym and what is not, so they won't warn you about the issue. That said, I always found `uRL` (and similar) ugly as hell and in this case I skip the conventions (and AFAIK I am not the only one to do so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write getters and setters. Or better - let your IDE generate them automatically. Otherwise you break the encapsulation.

Optionally you can use http://projectlombok.org/ and write it like this using annotations:

```
@Getter @Setter
private String name;
```

The code generation is done compile time.

Have a look at [This](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/226428/naming-convention-of-getters-and-setters) site

Edit:-

example:

```
public class Test {

protected double WIDTH;
public double getWidTh() {
  return WIDTH;
}
public void setWidTh(double wIDTH) {
  WIDTH = wIDTH;
}
public static void main(String []args){
  Test t = new Test();
  t.setWidTh(2);
  Object c = t;
  Class klazz = c.getClass();
  try {
    for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : Introspector
    .getBeanInfo(klazz).getPropertyDescriptors()) {
      Method m = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();
      if (m != null)
        System.out.println(m.invoke(c));
      }
  } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IntrospectionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Comment: I know that. I asked about naming convention of field URL without violating java naming convention and also with a proper method name.

Comment: Then you have to change the methods name manually,**java.beans.BeanInfo,java.beans.IntrospectionException,java.beans.Introspector,java.beans.PropertyDescriptor** will work just fine with getURL/setURL and variable name URL because getters and setters are called get/set then the First letter of variable capital so (**getURL** ,**getUrl**,**getUrL**,**getURl**) will work fine

Comment: @iCode see [this](http://justpaste.it/mxpx) code , i used java.beans.BeanInfo and java.beans.PropertyDescriptor

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to do it manually or you can change the name of the field to URL but in that case you will not be following the Java naming conventions.